# WPF + Expander control issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application in which i want to add "Expander" control.

The XAML code is like this

```
<Expander Header="More Options" Margin="30,286,0,0"  Height="145" Width="547">
   <Grid>
      <TextBox Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,286,0,0" Name="logsTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="547" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
   </Grid>
</Expander>
```

The textBox gets updated with the output of the bat file(which runs using Process).

when I run my application, textBox is not visible when expanding the expander.

What property I have to set to make it visible when expanding the expander?

Thanks

Comment: You have set some big margin values. What's the size of your Window? It's possible, that the textbox is way out of its boundaries.

Comment: My window size is  Height="480" Width="635"

Comment: I ran your Xaml.  The Text Block is visible, it is just way down in the bottom.

Comment: did you try to remove the Margin from the textbox ?

Comment: Thanks  Ondrej Janacek, Garry Vass, ZSH. Its visible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin property is applied to the parent's region.

Your declaration...

```
<TextBox Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,286,0,0" Name="logsTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="547" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
```

...indicates that the TextBox should appear inside the Expander and 286 units BELOW the Exander's top.   Remove the TextBox margin and you will see it as expected.